# Query Across Join Exclusively

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write a query to determine who, in my company, has roles that I specify, and no others.

The tables are User, UserRole, and Role.  An (incorrect) example is below and I have tried a few different ways like this, but they all seem to return a user when they just contain the roles.

```sql
select U.Username from User U
    join UserRole UR on U.UserID = UR.UserID
    join Role R on UR.RoleID = R.RoleID
where R.RoleName in ('Role1', 'Role2', 'Role3')
```

Example User table

| User ID | UserName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe |
| 2 | Bob |

Example UserRole Table

| UserID | RoleID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |

Example Role Table

| RoleID | RoleName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Admin |
| 2 | SysAdmin |
| 3 | Manager |

For example, I want to query for everyone that **only** has the SysAdmin, and manager roles. Although Joe has those roles I don't want him to be included in the result.

I feel like there is something simple that I am missing.  However, after doing research online, I am unable to find a similar scenario.

Comment: For me your query looks fine. Could you please explain why you are not satisfied with it

Comment: The query is supposed to be exclusive, which I tried to explain (poorly) in my question. I want Users that ONLY have the roles suggested, and no more.

Comment: If you add some sample data and the desired output it will be easier to provide the right answer, but I posted my best guess anyway.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your requirements:

```
select U.Username 
from User U
join UserRole UR on U.UserID = UR.UserID
join Role R on UR.RoleID = R.RoleID
where R.RoleName in ('Role1', 'Role2', 'Role3')
GROUP BY U.Username 
HAVING COUNT(R.RoleName)=3
```

The above is untested but should give you enough hints to solve your problem